# Creating Random Numbers in C# using a unique ID

Tags: c#

How do i write a code in C# which generates a set of random numbers and each set created should have a unique ID .So if that range and unique number is given again the same random numbers should be generated.

Eg Range is 1 - 100 
Random Numbers generated by system is 5, 10 ,15 and for this range a unique ID is created 123,432,876.

Now if i enter the same range 1-100 and the same unique ID 123,432,876. My output should be 5,10 and 15 only.

Comment: Not sure, when you figure it out and run into a problem with your code let us know and we'll try and help. In the meantime, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Welcome. This is not a free code writing service. Please become familiar with the term of use.

Comment: Use current time with milliseconds and then create a serial number of it, This will generate a unique ID

Answer (score 1):

Just use [the constructor of `Random` that takes a seed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int seed = 12345; // Your seed goes here.
Random rng = new Random(seed);
```

Every `Random` created with a particular seed will generate the same sequence of random numbers.

This is exactly what the seed is for.